# A bank account problem

Tags: probability

So this is a problem I'm stuck on. A bank accepts rolls of coins of 1 cents and provides a credit of 50 cents without counting the coins of each roll. Assume that a roll contains 49 cents with probability $0.3$, that it contains 50 cents with probability $0.6$ and that it contains $51$ cents with probability $0.1$.

How many rolls are necessary in order to get a probability of $0.99$ of a net loss for the bank?

Comment: Do you have any attempts to show?

Comment: Let $n_{i}$ with $i=\{49,50,51\}$ be the number of rolls with $i$ cents. In order for the bank to incur in a loss $n_{49}>n_{51}$.

Comment: Suggestion: Apply the Central Limit Theorem to approximate the gain or loss from $n$ rolls by a Normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Use trinomial coefficients for the probability w, that you get, within n rolls, u times a roll with (-1), v times a roll with 0 and (n-u-v) times a roll with +1 cent:
w = n!/(u!*v!*(n - u - v)!)*.3^u*.6^v*.1^(n - u - v).
Then sum up the probabilities that will result in a loss (with 0..u..n and 0..v..n-u):
(First initialize wneg=0):...If[w * u * (-1) < w*(n - u - v)*(+1), wneg = wneg + w].
A table {n, wneg} shows, that n = 9 is not enough (wneg(9) = 0.989922), but n = 10 is enough: wneg(10) = 0.993953.

You need 10 rolls for a probability of > 99% for a net loss of the bank.

Comment: Please, write your answer using usual LaTeX code. Your answer seems quite interesting, but I do not understand your notations.